# Weird issue launching yii script

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am getting a weird issue with a yii2 application (based in yii2-app-advanced) in the server, the thing is that the app frontend and backend are running ok, but the console tool (the yii script) is not working and is not throwing any errors.

Doing some debug by printing I have been able to track the issue to the requires calls in this block of code inside the script:

```
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/console/config/main-local.php'
);
```

But I have no idea why the requires calls are failing without throw any errors. The config paths are ok and the files has no syntax errors (my local copy with same php and mysql versions works ok)

I have other yii2 apps in the server and they are working just ok.

Any tip will be really helpful because this thing is driving me crazy...

Comment: What is the output of calling `./yii` in the console?

Comment: have you tried to output the path in the `require` section that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that was a corrupted file in the project or composer, I Have cloned the project again, cleaned the composer cache, and installed the vendors, and now is working ok.